# Android - EBADF (Bad file number) OnClickInfoMarker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have searched related issues but can't find it. I create an InfoWindowMarker which shows Picture, Name and Address. Then i create OnInfoWindowClickListener that will showing Latitude and Longitude of selected Marker. But when i click the Info Window i got this error message.

Logcat:

> com.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx E/Zygote﹕ Zygote:  error closing descriptor
>       libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
>               at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
>               at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:221)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:713)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:649)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

InfoWindowAdapter:

```
public GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter CustomMarkerInfo = new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        ImageView ivRow = (ImageView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.ivRowImage);
        TextView locationName = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvRowTitle);
        TextView locationAddress = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.tvRowTitle2);
        Bitmap locationImage;

        locationName.setText(marker.getTitle());
        locationAddress.setText(marker.getSnippet());
        URL imageURL;
        try {
            imageURL = new URL(markerInfo.get(marker.getId()));
            locationImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
            ivRow.setImageBitmap(locationImage);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return viewGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {return null;}
};
```

OnInfoWindowClickListener:

```
 private GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener onInfoWindowClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        LatLng myLatLng = myLatLng();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myLatLng.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {

    }
};

private LatLng myLatLng(){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    String provider;
    Location location;
    LatLng myLatLng = null;

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS tidak aktif.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
    }else{
        provider = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
    }


    if(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider) == null){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,2000,10,locationListener);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location == null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tidak dapat menemukan lokasi saat ini, coba lagi.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            myLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        }
    }else{
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        myLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    }
    return myLatLng == null ? myLatLng() : myLatLng;
}
```

Thanks for any solution.

Update: Markers created from loaded JSON. If it is could causing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a threading issue. Your `viewGroup` is returned before your image is load from the URL. An easy way to solve the problem is to use the third party image loading library `Picasso`.

Sample code:

```
 ImageView imageView = (ImageView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.ivRowImage);
 if (not_first_time_showing_info_window) {
     Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("YOUR_IMG_URL").into(imageView);
 } else { // if it's the first time, load the image with the callback set
     not_first_time_showing_info_window=true;
     Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("YOUR_IMG_URL").into(imageView,new InfoWindowRefresher(marker));
 }
```

And then you can have a private helper method to make sure the asynchronous shown in the first click:

```
 private class InfoWindowRefresher implements Callback {
        private Marker markerToRefresh;

        private InfoWindowRefresher(Marker markerToRefresh) {
            this.markerToRefresh = markerToRefresh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            markerToRefresh.showInfoWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {}
    }
```

You can refer to this GitHub page for complete implementation: https://github.com/jbj88817/GoogleMap-InfoWindow-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bjiang/map_ex/MainActivity.java

If you really want to do it with ImageLoader, you can check out this post: http://androidfreakers.blogspot.com/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html
(But it is more complicated compared to using Picasso to load from URL)

Comment: I tried to using Default Info Window but still face same issue. I'll try to using Picasso in my previous activity which use AsyncTask to load image. Maybe it'll fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you, i change all image loader to Picasso and Zygote error disappear.