# Zygote﹕ Zygote: error closing descriptor libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: android

I have the following exception

```
    05-27 19:42:04.062  19295-19295/me.jt.jk E/Zygote﹕ Zygote:  error closing descriptor
        libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
                at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
                at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:224)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:705)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-27 19:42:04.369  19295-19295/me.jt.jk E/﹕ appName=me.jt.jk, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger
    05-27 19:42:04.369  19295-19295/me.jt.jk E/﹕ 0
    05-27 19:42:04.879  19295-19314/me.jt.jk
E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x5594a528 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x555748c0 arg=0x0
    05-27 19:42:04.879  19295-19314/me.jt.jk
 E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x5594a528 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=RSA
```

on the line of code which worked until now:

```
final HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - EBADF (Bad file number) OnClickInfoMarker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581178/android-ebadf-bad-file-number-onclickinfomarker)

Comment: This might be a threading issue.