# Zygote: error closing descriptor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What does this error mean and how to fix it..?

```
Zygote:error closing descriptor
libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)

at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:220)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:700)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have been using following imports on an application project, and have no idea from where is this error coming, although there isn't any problem during runtime.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
```

Will add all the required class and layouts, Here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.devs.fookart">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/profile_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/action_settings" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:label="@string/action_settings" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: External library:CircleImageView

Comment: Same error and stack trace reported in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489602/zygote-zygote-error-closing-descriptor-libcore-io-errnoexception-close-failed).  Are you doing anything with an HTTP client?

Comment: Yes in this one, but not in others where I see same error

Comment: I'm getting this error in every project in all of my devices. But it has no impact on apps.